# Fetching value from table and passing it in url

Tags: mysql

How can i use in table field values in the url

SQL Query wherein all 3 tables are joined

```
select * from nfojm_usedcar_variants cv 
        inner join nfojm_usedcar_products cp  
        inner join nfojm_usedcar_categories cc on  
        cc.id=cp.prod_cat_id and 
        cp.id=cv.v_prod_id and 
        cv.state='1' order by cv.id desc
```

Output as checked

Then it combines all 3 tables

1. nfojm_usedcar_variants
2. nfojm_usedcar_products
3. nfojm_usedcar_categories

However - all 3 tables have unique field i.e id (but with different values)

[image]

I need to pass on value of id and v_prod_id in a url
say url been :-

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_usedcar&pid='.$row->v_prod_id.'&vid='.$row->id.'">
```

But id been common field in most of the tables hence its not picking in correctly from nfojm_usedcar_variants,

Can some one help to modify  a function so as to fetch in value of id and v_prod_id from the respective table of nfojm_usedcar_variants

thanks

Comment: sure, document your schema with `show create table xyz` for each relevant table. Someone will bang it out

Comment: sorry dint get it

Comment: Let's say you have a table named `xyz` that is relevant to this question. Do the above, paste the output into you question with an [edit]. Do that for anything relevant to the question. Pictures don't help us (generally).

Comment: Hello, i have tried editing the question and put in all information to the best of my limited understanding on mysql, can you help in it now

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple tables in a join that share a common column name, and you need them, then alias them. Such as:

```
select a.id as aid,a.theName,b.id as bid,b.year
from tableA a
join tableB b
on b.id=a.id
```

then refer to those columns as `aid` and `bid` in your code that follows.

Try to avoid *Ever* doing a `select *`. Be explicit. You never know what comes flying out of a `select *` typically. And odds are you don't need it all. `Select *` is fine for messing around, but not for production code. And you can't control common column names with `select *`. We like to control things afterall, no?

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful and is in right direction and definite help. But how to do it when 3 tables are involved

Comment: Just add table 3, `c` ? Just keep joining away.

Comment: is it possible to connect with you offline (email), i am unsure of the stack policy and in no way intend to violate. may be i need you help on actual code file, if you wish to help. thnx